# What works better in minimizing scars? Silicone plasters or silicone gels?

Tags: dermatology, scar-tissue-scars, plastic-surgery

Are silicone plasters or silicone gels more effective for minimizing scarring and optimal healing of a one month-old scar?

Comment: Requests for personal medical advice are off-topic here, so I edited your question to comply.